# Block search spiders for specific directory with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, web-crawler

I'm trying to write .htaccess rewrite for page with categories and search filters.

I want to disallow the special places with .htaccess . **I have already specified places in robots.txt**, but spiders still crawling the places.

Places i want to allow to crawl:

- www.domain.com/path1.html
- www.domain.com/path1/path2.html
- www.domain.com/path1/path2/path3.html
- www.domain.com/path1/path2/path3.html
- www.domain.com/path4/path5.html

Places i want to disallow to crawl:

- www.domain.com/path1.html?search[param1]=value&...
- www.domain.com/path1/path2.html?search=param2&...
- www.domain.com/path1/path2/path3.html?searchHash=param3

As i understand .htaccess code for search param will look, something like this, but it's not correct and I'm stack..

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|yandex) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html\?search=.*$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot match `QUERY_STRING` in `RewriteRule`. You need to use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=.+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|yandex) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.html)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```